# Conditional cumulative distribution function of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am able to calculate the cumulative distribution function for a multivariate normal distribution, as I have both the means and covariances. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) gives the formula for calculating the conditional distribution. However, that is the conditional *probability* distribution function. Is it possible to calculate the conditional *cumulative* distribution function?

Right now I can directly calculate (with scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.cdf):

$P(X_1 \le a_1)$

I am trying to calculate:

$P(X_1 \le a_1 | X_2 \le a_2 )$

Thanks!

Comment: Conditional on what? If you mean that $[X_1, X_2]$ are jointly normal then what is the cdf of the distribution $P(X_2 | X_1)$ then since this conditional is itself a multivariate normal the cdf will be the cdf of the (conditioned) normal distribution which you say you can evaluate.

Comment: Edited the question to be a bit more specific. If I understand correctly, the conditioned distribution would give me $P(X_1 | X_2 = a_2)$, and so I can calculate $P(X_1 \le a_1 | X_2 = a_2)$, but I don't know how to directly get $P(X_1 \le a_1 | X_2 \le a_2)$. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes more sense now, I think what you want is the multivariate normal truncated so that $ -\infty < X_2 \leq a$, or similar. I'm not certain about python implementations but for an R implementation have a look at [this](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010/RJ-2010-005/RJ-2010-005.pdf) and references and see if the idea is what you have in mind

Comment: Took a look, and that sounds promising. So I would be effectively looking at a multivariate normal conditioned on a multivariate normal truncated? Or could they both be truncated? And not sure if this changes anything, but if all the upper integration ranges ($a_1$, $a_2$) have the same values, does it simplify the problem at all? For example $a_1 = [5, 5, 5, ...]$ and $a_2 = [5, 5, 5, ...]$.